# Attempting to add to dict throws KeyError - Python3.5.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm programming a script to read some data from a pipe and parse the parameters. I've got a script like this:

```
def metadataScrape():
    current_line = ""
    line_finished = False
    with open("/tmp/shairport-sync-metadata") as f:
        for line in f:
            current_line += line[:-1]
            if current_line[-2:] == "m>":
                line_finished = True

            if line_finished:
                html_data = html.fromstring(current_line)
                data = html_data.xpath("//text()")
                decoded_data = [HexDecode(data[0]), HexDecode(data[1])]
                if len(data) == 4:
                    decoded_data.append(Base64Decode(data[3]))
                else:
                    decoded_data.append("")
                decoded_data.append(time.time())
                print(decoded_data)
                if decoded_data[0] == "ssnc":
                    ssnc_params[decoded_data[1]] == decoded_data[2:]
                elif decoded_data[0] == "core":
                    core_params[decoded_data[1]] == decoded_data[2:]

                current_line = ""
                line_finished = False
```

Whenever I run it, it appears to run fine until I get some data. For example, if I try to change the volume on the AirPlay machine (my project is an AirPlay speaker) it throws this as I try to add it to the dictionary:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    metadataScrape()
  File "/home/pi/python/metadata-reader.py", line 57, in metadataScrape
    ssnc_params[decoded_data[1]] == decoded_data[2:]
KeyError: 'pvol'
```

Just FYI, this is a sample of the sort of stuff I'm getting from the pipe:

```
<item><type>636f7265</type><code>6173676e</code><length>3</length>
<data encoding="base64">
UG9w</data></item>
<item><type>636f7265</type><code>6d696e6d</code><length>27</length>
<data encoding="base64">
Q3JhenkgaW4gTG92ZSAoZmVhdC4gSmF5LVop</data></item>
<item><type>636f7265</type><code>6173646b</code><length>1</length>
<data encoding="base64">
AA==</data></item>
<item><type>636f7265</type><code>63617073</code><length>1</length>
<data encoding="base64">
Ag==</data></item>
<item><type>73736e63</type><code>6d64656e</code><length>10</length>
<data encoding="base64">
MTE1NDkyNzQwMg==</data></item>
<item><type>73736e63</type><code>7072736d</code><length>0</length></item>
<item><type>73736e63</type><code>70656e64</code><length>0</length></item>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse `==` and `=`. You are not adding anything to the dictionary, you are attempting to compare something to an element that does not yet exist. `ssnc_params[decoded_data[1]] == decoded_data[2:]` must be `ssnc_params[decoded_data[1]] = decoded_data[2:]`. Same with `core_params`.

Comment: Thanks! How stupid was that, I must have slipped a finger :P Will accept when it lets me